# Changing event to on.click for searching terms

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this snippet found below which highlights and jumps to the searched term. The current snippet searches after each keystroke that the user inputs which is putting too much stress on the server. Instead I want it to `mark` and jump once the user presses enter or clicks the next button. I've tried change the following line but it's breaking the code. Any ideas?

```
$input.on("input", function() {
```

to

```
$nextBtn.on('click', function() {
```

Code here:

```
$(function() {

  // the input field
  var $input = $("input[type='search']"),
    // clear button
    $clearBtn = $("button[data-search='clear']"),
    // prev button
    $prevBtn = $("button[data-search='prev']"),
    // next button
    $nextBtn = $("button[data-search='next']"),
    // the context where to search
    $content = $(".content"),
    // jQuery object to save <mark> elements
    $results,
    // the class that will be appended to the current
    // focused element
    currentClass = "current",
    // top offset for the jump (the search bar)
    offsetTop = 50,
    // the current index of the focused element
    currentIndex = 0;

  /**
   * Jumps to the element matching the currentIndex
   */
  function jumpTo() {
    if ($results.length) {
      var position,
        $current = $results.eq(currentIndex);
      $results.removeClass(currentClass);
      if ($current.length) {
        $current.addClass(currentClass);
        position = $current.offset().top - offsetTop;
        window.scrollTo(0, position);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Searches for the entered keyword in the
   * specified context on input
   */
  $input.on("input", function() {
    var searchVal = this.value;
    $content.unmark({
      done: function() {
        $content.mark(searchVal, {
          separateWordSearch: true,
          done: function() {
            $results = $content.find("mark");
            currentIndex = 0;
            jumpTo();
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });

  /**
   * Clears the search
   */
  $clearBtn.on("click", function() {
    $content.unmark();
    $input.val("").focus();
  });

  /**
   * Next and previous search jump to
   */
  $nextBtn.add($prevBtn).on("click", function() {
    if ($results.length) {
      currentIndex += $(this).is($prevBtn) ? -1 : 1;
      if (currentIndex < 0) {
        currentIndex = $results.length - 1;
      }
      if (currentIndex > $results.length - 1) {
        currentIndex = 0;
      }
      jumpTo();
    }
  });
});
```

Working JSFiddle found here: https://jsfiddle.net/83nbm2rv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `$input.on('input')` to:

```
$input.on("keypress", function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    var searchVal = this.value;
    $content.unmark({
      done: function() {
        $content.mark(searchVal, {
          separateWordSearch: true,
          done: function() {
            $results = $content.find("mark");
            currentIndex = 0;
            jumpTo();
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

And that will handle pressing `enter` in the textbox. See this fiddle for the next button click update: https://jsfiddle.net/9g4xr765/

Basic approach was to functionalize the content marking and calling it on `$input` keypress, and also in next/previous click if there are no results.

There are still issues though, like if the value changes you can't use the next/previous button to search so that would require some additional work.

Comment: Hey Anthony thanks for the response, doesn't look like that's working either. Here is an updated link with that code: https://jsfiddle.net/t3khrg7a/

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you so much. Having trouble with the jQuery part.. Now if I want the next button to also search what would you recommend?

Comment: The next button is slightly trickier as it is also serving the purpose of taking to the next match. If there are results, should it just continue doing that?

Comment: That's what I'm hoping for, that if they click it it would take them to the first found result and if they click again to the next result.. the enter can even have the same feature if that's easier. if you keep clicking enter it jumps to next. What you think is easiest?

Comment: Updated with a new fiddle. Couldn't get dependencies to work in a snippet

Comment: Thanks again Anthony, I'm going to mark these as the correct answer.